# Telegram Bot, inline button

Tags: java, bots, telegram

How to define that inline button is pressed and how to get callbackdata using pengrad/telegram-bot-api library? I have this code to send message with inline keyboard button

```
private void approveAdmin(User u){
    User admin = userService.findByUserRole("ROLE_ADMIN");
    SendMessage sm = new SendMessage(admin.getChatId(),
            "Do you approve user: "+u.getfName()+" "+u.getlName()+" as admin?");
    sm.replyMarkup(new InlineKeyboardMarkup(new InlineKeyboardButton[]
            {new InlineKeyboardButton("Approve user.").callbackData(u.getIdUser().toString())}));
    BOT.execute(sm);
}
```

but how to handle update from inline button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below snippet may helps you:

```
GetUpdatesResponse updatesResponse = bot.execute(new GetUpdates());
List<Update> updates = updatesResponse.updates();
for (Update update : updates) {
    CallbackQuery callbackQuery = update.callbackQuery();
    if (callbackQuery != null)  {
        //use the callbackQuery object peroperties to provide the appropriate response
    }
    //to make the update handler fully functional, make sure to check other types of messages
}
```